# MOSFETs fail short on for brushed DC motor driver

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I am trying to design a motor driver for an electric car for a fuel efficiency competition. This is the first time I have designed anything like this, and so far I have come up with the design shown in the images. It works when the motor has no load, and when the motor is hooked up to a stationary bike. When it is hooked up to the stationary bike, it draws around 30-40A. When it is put in our car, however, the MOSFETs always fail short. I know it probably draws more than 40A then, but the MOSFETs, [FDP020N06B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FDP020N06B-108818.pdf), should be rated for at least 120A.

One image shows the full circuit and one with just what is on the PCB. The full circuit includes two contactors, one main contactor and one that just connects the motor. The second contactor is there because when the Arduino boots up, all the pins are high, so it is to prevent the motor from jerking on. The MOSFETs are in a half-H bridge configuration, driven by an IR2184 mosfet driver. This IC was recommended to us by other teams last year.[image: Full Circuit]
[image: Just what is on the board]

I am already aware of some design flaws, like how the resistors in parallel to the contactors are too low-valued (I was told that they help with sparking and the ones we used were also used in golf carts, but I guess not), and the fact that I could have probably used a pull-down resistor to pull down the IN pin while the Arduino turns on instead of adding a second contactor. I also know that I probably shouldn't have used screw terminals, but it was my first time designing a PCB so I wasn't sure that I wouldn't need to change pins. Either way it worked when we tested it but not in the real car. My question is, what could be causing the MOSFETs to fail short?

Some additional information:
-We want to run the whole system at 24V

- Once, the input decoupling capacitor for the voltage regulator blew up. I wasn't the one to solder it and nobody cared to look, so it could have been backward, but I doubt the person who soldered it made that mistake.
- The voltage regulator is one off of Amazon. It takes 36-9V input and outputs 12V. I wasn't sure how big the decoupling capacitors should be so I just found the biggest ones we had rated for more than 25V
- The circuit comes from the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2184.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c955e616d4) of the driver.
- Although in the schematic, the screw terminals all look the same, they are not. The ones for the motor and the battery are bigger than the rest.

Any tips are appreciated, and please forgive me if the answer is obvious. I don't really know a lot about electronics or what I'm doing.

Comment: Rated for 120 A under what conditions? I can promise you that rating is only with inordinately powerful cooling on the MOSFET.

Comment: Datasheet https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FDP020N06B-108818.pdf says it is package limited. I had a small heatsink on the lower MOSFET too.

Comment: @Wasiud what that line in the datasheet means is, if you managed to keep the metal tab at 25°C through heroic cooling efforts, the package would still get destroyed above 120A.

Comment: @Hearth Once a leg unsoldered itself, but I think that was just a bad solder job. Sometimes the legs would melt in half, but always after the MOSFET failed, since it shorted the battery.

Comment: @Wasiud You would need to cool it with liquid nitrogen to get adequate cooling to meet that spec. You need a higher-current FET, possibly a couple in parallel. An NTMTS0D4N04CL might be suitable, or possibly an IQD005N04NM6CG.

Comment: I never though heat could be an issue because they were never very hot to the touch. Do you think if I had 2 or 3 of FDP020N06Bs in parallel, it would work, or would you recommend a different MOSFET entirely?

Comment: A couple in parallel would probably work, but they'd need their own individual heatsinks and you'd need to do something to make sure the load is shared between them. Simply using a FET designed for higher current (like either of the ones I mentioned above, perhaps--but do some research for your specific use case) would be easier.

Comment: Sounds good. I will update the post next time I get to test it.

Comment: Current ratings on a MOSFET datasheet essentially mean nothing. Don't even look at them. Instead, look at the RSdon and package thermal resistance and calculate.

Comment: @DKNguyen So right.  IR started the specsmanship thing years ago.  Sure, if you can somehow keep the case at 25 C you can get a lot of current through the FET, but how meaningless is that?

Comment: @JohnD About as meaningless as figuring out how much stuff you can buy under the assumption that you somehow always keep the balance the same in your bank account.

Comment: @DKNguyen How would I calculate that? I try to calculate watts and then multiply by the rated C/W but I keep getting crazy high numbers.

Comment: @Wasiud Sounds about right. If ignoring switching loss (which is the trickiest part) and only looking at conduction, you just go I^2R for Watts. Don't forget the rise in RDSon due to temperature. It is in a graph usually at the end of the datasheet. Typically 1.5x - 2.0x RDson at room temperature at the limits of operating temperature. If junction-to-ambient gives crazy high numbers that means you need a heatsink so you can use junction-heatsink-ambient thermal resistances. But this should be expected for 120A. You can't expect a single TO-220 to pass that. A screw terminal SOT-227, maybe.